# How to log application events in android?

Tags: android, logging

I would like to know if there any way to log application events in android..and to display back the log information??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [adb logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) to view the event logger.

To put events into logcat, use the [android.util.Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class. Mainly, you'll be putting statements like `Log.d(TAG, message)` in key areas of your application.

Comment: Can we able to display the log information back to device screen output??

Comment: Not that I know of, unless you put in statements to display dialogs or change certain text on an activity (except that would be a lot of work). The easiest way is to use logcat. If you're using an emulator,  you don't have to do anything special; just enter 'adb logcat' into command line. If you are using an actual phone, enable USB debugging on your phone, and then use 'adb logcat' in command line.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan: I think there are apps on the Market for viewing the LogCat data on the device.